# how generate signed apk in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to generate signed apk in flutter but i dont have this option in build menu.
when i open editing tool in new window, show me error  of gradle. and buid menu dont have any option for genrate signed apk
it is my gradle wrapper code.[image]

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

[image]

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1fByAsqQRk Refer this video

Comment: thank you. this video is in mac. i have windows. can u guide me step by step. im new in command line

Comment: and i have key from first project that i coded native.

Comment: You can follow the same steps in that video. Even i have windows and i used the same steps. Only difference would be when you have to paste the path for generating the key. Enter proper windows directory structure. Do let me know if have any doubts, in case you already have a key then you don't need to generate another one you can use the same key

Comment: thank you so much. i test it step by step. and i think because i have key from past its easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps

1. Go to in your project & then Tools -> Flutter -> Open for Editing in Android Studio
2. Then Select New Window option
3. Wait for the project synchronization to finish. After that
   Go to Build -> GenerateSigned Bundle/APK...
4. Select Android App Bundle or APK Option as per your need. (usually app bundle is the best option) and click Next button.
5. Select Create new.. option to generate new Signed key (When you release your app First Time)

you will have to fill the form to create it

**Key store Path -**

Path where your key store file i.e .jks file stored (as shown in above image). [Best way Select the path within your project directory.]

**Key store password -**

Enter password e.g. 123456

**Key alias -**

Enter Key alias (Name of .jks file) e.g. key

**Key Password -**

Enter Key password (Choose different password than Key store password) e.g. key123456

Validity(years) - Keep it as it is or change as per your requirements.

**Certificate -**

Fill certificate information (Not all fields are mandatory)

6. Select build variants - release and Signature versions both V1 and V2 respectively and click Finish button.

After all this you should have the output of the build process

Comment: thanks but in question i said i dnt have this menu in androdi studio. please my image

Comment: Did the option not appear after the first 3 steps?

Comment: i dont have 3rth step in my android menu.